# Is Lily Rank useful for anything other than enabling skills?

Tags: neptunia-v

Lily Ranks had a direct effect on the story and Events in Neptunia Mk2; however in V lily Ranks are explicitly used to enable Coupling Skills and other special effects, and they're also much harder to rank up (once per combination of characters instead of once per character, or N<sup>2</sup> instead of N).

Are Lily Ranks still important for anything special, or do I just use them to unlock the Lily Effect/EXE Drive skills and that's all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lily Ranks have two major effects. The first effect is that they enable, as you note, characters to support each other in battle when they are paired as a front-line/support. Each character has two benefits they can provide the front line character, and two EX Finishers that can be used from the support position. Certain character pairs also have Coupling Skills, which are EXE Drive Attacks that can be performed when the two are coupled together. In all of these cases, a specific numeric Lily Rank level is required between the two in order to have access to the bonus or the attack.

As a trivia note, Neptune, Noire, and Vert all have their support EX Finishers as gun attacks from the first Neptunia game. Blanc's Jaeger Kugel is also from the first game, but as her ultimate gun attack is an SP skill (Gefahrlichsten), she just has a brand new EX Finisher as the second one.

The second major effect is item creation. Certain high level recipes require you to have two characters to have a certain Lily Rank level (usually 7 or 8). Most of these are just the ultimate weapons for various goddesses, though, so usually you've had enough time to buddy up. Maybe.